# How secured is giving input data to WorkManager's Worker?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

```
    Data data = new Data.Builder()
            .putString("APIKEY", apiKey)
            .build();
    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.UNMETERED).build();
    WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(AppContext.getApplicationContext());
    OneTimeWorkRequest workRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UploadWorker.class).setInputData(data).setConstraints(constraints).build();
    workManager.enqueue(workRequest);
```

How safe is apiKey thats being sent to the worker?
Since It is guaranteed that Worker would run eventually, I am guessing they write the inputs to the disk, so will anyone with root access be able to read it? or is it encrypted in some way? if it isnt safe to do it that way, how can we make a safe transition of the apiKey to the Worker (which can run in different process than the request enqueue)?

Answer (score 1):

> will anyone with root access be able to read it?
> Yes.

WorkManager usses a room database to persist all its data to guarantee the execution of the workers, including the input/output data and any progress that you publish during the execution of your worker.

You can use the Database inspector in Android Studio to see which data are stored by WorkManager.

You may pass the apiKey in an encrypted format as an input data and only decrypt it in the Worker when needed. Or you may pass the apiKey as a additional parameter using Dagger/Hilt or any other DI system that you may use in your app.